Rundeck commands no longer working after upgrading nodes to Ubuntu 24.04
Im using rundeck (installed on a Ubuntu 22.04 server) to run commands on a few remote nodes.
Unfortunately the scheduled jobs are not working anymore on nodes that have been upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04
I've tested to just run a simpel "uname -a" command on a remote Ubuntu 24.04 node and get the following error:
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ansible.module_utils.six.moves' node01 | FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to node01 closed.\r\n",
    "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1727773197.2698286-5555-256622891592982/AnsiballZ_command.py\", line 102, in <module>\r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1727773197.2698286-5555-256622891592982/AnsiballZ_command.py\", line 94, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1727773197.2698286-5555-256622891592982/AnsiballZ_command.py\", line 37, in invoke_module\r\n    from ansible.module_utils import basic\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_ansible.legacy.command_payload_11u5rz__/ansible_ansible.legacy.command_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py\", line 176, in <module>\r\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ansible.module_utils.six.moves'\r\n",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1 } Failed: AnsibleError: ERROR: Ansible execution returned with non zero code. Execution failed: 1194949 in project Systems: [Workflow result: , step failures: {1=Dispatch failed on 1 nodes: [node01: AnsibleError: ERROR: Ansible execution returned with non zero code. + {dataContext=MultiDataContextImpl(map={}, base=null)} ]}, Node failures: {node01=[AnsibleError: ERROR: Ansible execution returned with non zero code. + {dataContext=MultiDataContextImpl(map={}, base=null)} ]}, status: failed]

The rundeck server runs Rundeck version 5.6.0, Ansible version 2.10.8 and Python 3.10.12.
The node01 server runs Python 3.12.3
Update:
After some more digging into logs I found this issue: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/9278. This is the same problem I'm facing. Because of this error, the nodes seem to not refresh correctly and Rundeck is loading cached model data.

My Advise is to
1- update Ansible
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ansible
2- Check Python Version
ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3

3- Install Missing Modules
pip install six

